# Scaladoc from IDEA or Maven

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, scaladoc

I'm using Maven for builds and IntelliJ IDEA with the Scala plugin. The project runs and debugs fine using the Scala 2.10.3 dependencies in my pom.

But when I try to use IDEA to generate Scaladocs from my whole project It literally does nothing, no output.

Related, I'd like to produce Scaladocs from Maven too. I've got Javadocs for the java parts of the project. There are instructions for doing this with sbt but nothing I can find about doing it with Maven.

my IDEA project has the following Scala libs

```
scala-library-2.10.3.jar
scala-reflect-2.10.0.jar
scalatest_2.10-2.0.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add maven plugin to have scala docs .  Add following code to your pom.xml

```
<project>

 <reporting>
<plugins>
  ...
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
  </plugin>
  ...
</plugins>
```

and Place scala sources files in :

```
src/main/scala
```

after that  use following maven goals:

```
# generate a site
mvn site
```

or

```
# generate only the doc
mvn scala:doc
```

and docs results will be under:

```
target/site/scaladocs/
```

try following link for more details:
http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/maven-scala-plugin/usage_doc.html

Comment: That solves the maven scaladocs, I had the plugin, just didn't know the CLI.

Comment: Great answer! Works in general for porting from Java to Scala.